# How to use XPath contains() here?

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm trying to learn XPath. I looked at the other `contains()` examples around here, but nothing that uses an *AND* operator. I can't get this to work:

```
//ul[@class='featureList' and contains(li, 'Model')]
```

On:

```
...
<ul class="featureList">

<li><b>Type:</b> Clip Fan</li><li><b>Feature:</b> Air Moved: 65 ft.
    Amps: 1.1
    Clip: Grips any surface up to 1.63"
    Plug: 3 prong grounded plug on heavy duty model
    Usage: Garage, Workshop, Dorm, Work-out room, Deck, Office & more.</li><li><b>Speed Setting:</b> 2 speeds</li><li><b>Color:</b> Black</li><li><b>Power Consumption:</b> 62 W</li><li><b>Height:</b> 14.5"</li><li><b>Width:</b> Grill Diameter: 9.5"</li><li><b>Length:</b> 11.5"</li>

<li><b>Model #: </b>CR1-0081-06</li>
<li><b>Item #: </b>N82E16896817007</li>
<li><b>Return Policy: </b></li>
</ul>
...
```

Comment: this works for me, I tested it on http://www.whitebeam.org/library/guide/TechNotes/xpathtestbed.rhtm

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You are only looking at the first `li` child in the query you have instead of looking for any `li` child element that may contain the text, `'Model'`. What you need is a query like the following:

```
//ul[@class='featureList' and ./li[contains(.,'Model')]]
```

This query will give you the elements that have a `class` of `featureList` with one or more `li` children that contain the text, `'Model'`.

Comment: +1 -- The "./" is a bit misleading - it suggests that anything other than the current node would be taken into account when you leave it out, but in fact it is redundant: "//ul[@class='featureList' and li[contains(.,'Model')]]" is the same thing.

Comment: Yup, I was just being specific. Quite possibly overly specific.

Comment: If there is no `li` with `Model` in `ul`, then the `and` condition will fail. So `and` condition returns `false` on the empty set, is it correct?

Answer (score 65):

I already gave my +1 to Jeff Yates' solution.

Here is a quick explanation why your approach does not work. This:

```
//ul[@class='featureList' and contains(li, 'Model')]
```

encounters a limitation of the `contains()` function (or any other string function in XPath, for that matter).

The first argument is supposed to be a string. If you feed it a node list (giving it "`li`" does that), a conversion to string must take place. But this conversion is done for the first node in the list only.

In your case the first node in the list is `<li><b>Type:</b> Clip Fan</li>` (converted to a string: "`Type: Clip Fan`") which means that this:

```
//ul[@class='featureList' and contains(li, 'Type')]
```

would actually select a node!

Comment: nice one been struggling to figure out why queries like: ".//td[contains(.//*,'something')]" only work to a depth of 1.  I'd figured out how to make it work but wasnt sure how the above was working at all.  What I actually needed was ".//td[.//*[contains(.,'something')]]"

Answer (score 22):

<sup>This is a new answer to an old question about a ***common misconception*** about `contains()` in XPath...</sup>

Summary: `contains()` means *contains a substring*, **not** *contains a node*.

### Detailed Explanation

This XPath is often misinterpreted:

```
//ul[contains(li, 'Model')]
```

**Wrong interpretation:**
Select those `ul` elements that *contain* an `li` element with `Model` in it.

This is wrong because

1. `contains(x,y)` expects `x` to be a string, and
2. the XPath rule for converting multiple elements to a string is [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of
> the node in the node-set that is first in [document order](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-document-order). If the
> node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.

**Right interpretation:** Select those `ul` elements whose ***first*** `li` child has a [***string-value***](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) that ***contains*** a `Model` substring.

### Examples

**XML**

```
<r>
  <ul id="one">
    <li>Model A</li>
    <li>Foo</li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="two">
    <li>Foo</li>
    <li>Model A</li>
  </ul>
</r>
```

**XPaths**

- `//ul[contains(li, 'Model')]` selects the `one` `ul` element.

**Note:** The `two` `ul` element is not selected because the string-value of the first `li` child
of the `two` `ul` is `Foo`, which does not contain the `Model` substring.

- `//ul[li[contains(.,'Model')]]` selects the `one` and `two` `ul` elements.

**Note:** Both `ul` elements are selected because `contains()` is applied to each `li` individually.  (Thus, the tricky multiple-element-to-string conversion rule is avoided.) Both `ul` elements do have an `li` child whose string value contains the `Model` substring -- position of the `li` element no longer matters.

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)

Answer (score -7):

Paste my `contains` example here:

```
//table[contains(@class, "EC_result")]/tbody
```

Comment: There is no `table` element or `EC_result` class value in OP's code.  ***This answer makes no sense here and should be deleted.***