# XPath wildcard in attribute value

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

I have the following XPath to match attributes of the class span:

```
//span[@class='amount']
```

I want to match all elements that have the class attribute of "amount" but also may have other classes as well. I thought I could do this:

```
//span[@class='*amount*']
```

but that doesn't work...how can I do this?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Use the following expression:

```
//span[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), ' amount ')]
```

You could use `contains` on its own, but that would also match classes like `someamount`. Test the above expression on the following input:

```
<root>
  <span class="test amount blah"/>
  <span class="amount test"/>
  <span class="test amount"/>
  <span class="amount"/>
  <span class="someamount"/>
</root>
```

It will select the first four `span` elements, but not the last one.

Comment: If suppose, I want to retrieve the text content inside the span tag then what will be the code. I have stored the result in nodelist and tried to print the content using nodelist.item(0).getFirstChild().getNodeValue(). But this doesn't return anything. Please help me out.

Comment: Interesting how a total of four (2 x 2) blanks are needed.

Answer (score 26):

You need to use contains method. See [How to use XPath contains() here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064968/how-to-use-xpath-contains-here)

`//span[contains(@class,'amount')]`

Comment: Unfortunately, that will also match `class="lookamountain"`.  @lwburk has the right answer.