# XPath for text after <br/>

Tags: html, xml, xpath, codeception

Looking to get the XPath of $2.00  with this block:

```
<td class="undefined" colspan="6">
   <table class="history-bill-payments" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="99%">
<thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
      <td valign="top">04/19/2016</td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align:right; height:">
         $3.00
         <br/>
         $2.00
      </td>
```

I have tried these but to no avail

```
$I->CanSeeElement("//table[contains(tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/following-sibling::br)]"); 
$I->CanSeeElement("//table[contains(tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/preceding-sibling::br/text(),'$2.00')]"); 
$I->CanSeeElement("//table[contains(tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/following-sibling::br/text(),'$2.00')]");
```

Using firepath in Firefox I get this XPath

> html/body/div[4]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]

I was able to get the xpath of $3.00

```
$I->CanSeeElement("//table[contains(tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text(),'$3.00')]");
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In XPath 1.0, given a node-set, `contains()` would only evaluates the first node in the set. That's why your initial XPath successfully find text node that contains `'$3.00'`, but not the one that contains `'$2.00'`.

XPath expression that is close to the way your *xpath of $3.00* works would be as follow :

```
//table[tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/text()[contains(.,'$2.00')]]
```

The XPath above works by applying `contains()` on individual text node instead of passing multiple text nodes at once.

Comment: would I be putting the $3.00 instead of the $2.00 in your example?

Comment: @TheBugCollector $2.00. I assumed you want to find the text by keyword $2.00 now, no?

Answer (score 6):

### `td` with certain contents

From your trials, it seems you're fine with keying off of `$2.00` literally, so you could use this XPath 2.0 expression to get the `td` that ends with `$2.00`:

```
//td[ends-with(normalize-space(), '$2.00')]
```

Note that browsers don't generally support XPath 2.0, so use this XPath 1.0 expression if running within a browser and you're ok with `$2.00` appearing anywhere within the `td`:

```
//td[contains(.,'$2.00')]
```

### Text following a `br`

If you don't want to literally specify the `$2.00`, you'll have to state some other invariant constraint.  For example, this XPath will return the string that follows the `br` contained within a `td` that starts with `$3.00`:

```
normalize-space(//td[starts-with(normalize-space(),'$3.00')]/br/following::text())
```

### See also

- [XPath `contains()` works differently in XPath v1.0 vs v2.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064968/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)

Answer (score 4):

If you need, just add table id or any other specific locator.

```
xpath=//table//tr/td[2]/text()[2]
```

Comment: Ok, somebody downvoted working xpath, so I guess the question is looking exactly for '$2.00', thus a bit of improvement - xpath=//table//tr/td[2]/text()[2 and contains(.,'$2.00')] but still it's pretty simple and working

Comment: i tried your answer and got malrformed xpath error see link http://prntscr.com/au6jk8

Comment: removed the extra / before the tr and it worked but couldnt find the $2.00

Comment: ok. probably the code structure is wider than in the given example. In the initial xpaths there are multiple table elements. We need to specify locator a bit more. With @class attribute, you can find the closest parent. 

if you want to try xpath=//table[@class='history-bill-payments']//tr/td[2]/text()[2] .. But anyway, the main point with the selection wast the last part /text()[2]