# How to use XPath contains() for specific text?

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

Say we have an HTML table which basically looks like this:

```
2|1|28|9|
3|8|5|10|
18|9|8|0|
```

I want to select the cells which contain only 8 and nothing else, that is, only 2nd cell of row2 and 3rd cell of row3.

This is what I tried: `//table//td[contains(.,'8')]`. It gives me all cells which contain 8. So, I get unwanted values 28 and 18 as well.

How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** Here is a sample table if you want to try your xpath. Use the calendar on the left side-https://sfbay.craigslist.org/sfc/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Be careful of the **`contains()`** function.

It is a common ***mistake*** to use it to test if an ***element contains a value***.  What it really does is test if a ***string contains a substring***.  So, `td[contains(.,'8')]` takes the string value of `td` (`.`) and tests if it contains any `'8'` substrings.  This might be what you want, but often it is not.

This XPath,

```
//td[.='8']
```

will select all `td` elements whose [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) **equals** `8`.

Alternatively, this XPath,

```
//td[normalize-space()='8']
```

will select all `td` elements whose [normalize-space()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) string-value **equals** `8`.  (The [normalize-space()](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space) XPath function strips leading and trailing whitespace and replaces sequences of whitespace characters with a single space.)

### Notes:

- Both will work even if the 8 is inside of another element such as a
  `a`, `b`, `span`, `div`, etc.
- Both will ***not*** match `<td>gr8t</td>`, `<td>123456789</td>`, etc.
- Using `normalize-space()` will ignore leading or trailing whitespace
  surrounding the `8`.

### See also:

- [Why is contains(text(), "string" ) not working in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71253563/290085)

Answer (score 6):

Try the following xpath, which will select the whole text contents rather than partial matches:

```
//table//td[text()='8']
```

Edit: Your example HTML has a tags inside the td elements, so the following will work:

```
//table//td/a[text()="8"]
```

See example in php here: https://3v4l.org/56SBn

Comment: This does not work. Please try the xpath in the link I have now added to the question. Thanks.