# Xpath conditional branch

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am new to XPath and I want to differentiate between these 2 XPath.

```
1) /*/*:Employee/*:Firstname/*:Name[contains(.,abc)]
2) /*/*:Employee/*:Firstname/*:Name[abc]
```

I have tried to google it but I am not getting a clear idea.

Could you please explain this difference in a simple way?

Answer (score 2):

`contains` is a string function, that checks if the first string contains the second string (or if you like, if the second string is a substring of the first). Where an argument to a string function is a node (like `Name`) it will get the string value of that node to use. It is not used to check if a node contains a specific child node.

So, `Name[contains(.,abc)]` is saying "Does the string value of the `Name` element contain the string value of the child `abc` element?"

This is an odd thing to do, because it will always be true for all `Name` elements. The string value of a node includes the text of all descendants. And if there was no child `abc`, the string value would be an empty string, and so the expression would still be true.

For example, if the node was `<Name>1<abc>2</abc></Name>` the string value of `Name` would be "12", which obviously contains the string value of `abc`, which is "2".

On the other hand `Name[abc]` is getting the `Name` element if a child `abc` exists, regardless of what the string value is. Thus it would match `<Name><abc /></Name>` but not `<Name/>`.

(It's possible, the first expression should be `Name[contains(.,'abc')]`, in which case it would match `Name` elements which contained the string "abc". Thus it would match `<Name>abcdef</Name>` but not `<Name>cdefgh</Name>`)

Comment: Good answer.   OP: See also [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)