# Selenium XPath merge spans text and find element that contains substring

Tags: html, xml, selenium, xpath

I have problem creating Selenium query to select specific element from list using XPath.
I've tried `//li[contains(text(), 'Addressing machine wholesaling')]` but seems I need to merge inner spans somehow. Is there any way to do this?

Here is the example of list. I need to select first `li` element at this case.

```
<ul aria-labelledby="businessActivitySuggestionsProbableHeader1" class="anzsicList probable">
   <li activity="55" index="0" role="option" class="">
       <span class="matchText">Addressing</span>
       <span class="matchText">machine</span>
       <span class="matchText">wholesaling</span>
   </li>
   <li activity="4554" index="1" role="option" class="">
       <span class="matchText">Machine</span> manufacturing (including accounting, 
       <span class="matchText">addressing</span>, business, enveloping, letter folding, numbering, photocopying or duplicating)
   </li>
</ul>
```

If it's impossible maybe there other way to do that rather then using XPath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//li[normalize-space() = 'Addressing machine wholesaling']
```

will select your first `li` element, as requested.

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)