# Why is contains(text(), "string" ) not working in XPath?

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, xpath, screen-scraping

I have written this expression `//*[contains(text(), "Brand:" )]` for the below HTML code.

```html
<div class="info-product mt-3">
  <h3>Informazioni prodotto</h3>


  Brand: <span class="brand_title font-weight-bold text-uppercase"><a href="https://mammapack.com/brand/ava">Ava</a></span><br> SKU: 8002910009960<br> Peso Lordo: 0.471 kg <br> Dimensioni: 44.00 × 145.00 × 153.00 mm<br>

  <p class="mt-2">
    AVA BUCATO A MANO E2 GR.380</p>
</div>
```

The xpath that I have written is not working I want to select Node that contains text `Brand:`. Can someone tell me my mistake?

Answer (score 4):

Your XPath,

```
//*[contains(text(), "Brand:")]
```

in XPath 1.0 will select all elements whose first text node child contains a `"Brand:"` substring.  In XPath 2.0 it is an error to call `contains()` with a sequence of more than one item as the first argument.

This XPath,

```
//*[text()[contains(., "Brand:")]]
```

will select all elements with a text node child whose string value contains a `"Brand:"` substring.

### See also

- [XPath 1.0 vs 2.0+ different `contains()` behavior explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)
- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Comment: Thanks for the update! This is what I wanted to ask you about. Why can't I upvote here twice?

Comment: @Prophet, thanks.   The old Q/A on this topic also didn't adequately address the XPath 1.0 vs 2.0+ difference, so I've [added a very detailed answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085) too to remedy that.