# Finding phone numbers which start with a certain string with XPath

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, xpath

[image]

I want to find the phone number from these websites with XPath.

I tried with

```
//*[starts-with(text(),’+49’)]
```

and other similar combinations but it doesn't work. Anyone who can give me some advice?

Comment: You should add HTML-sample as text not as picture. You might also specify the programming language and web-scraping tool that you're using

Comment: I've answered your question this time, but @JaSON is correct:  Please post a [mcve] that allows us to test solutions against HTML or XML posted as text, formatted as code -- never posted as an image.  Thank you.

Comment: Don't say that it "doesn't work". Tell us how it fails.

Answer (score 1):

This XPath,

```
//text()[starts-with(normalize-space(), '+49')]
```

will select all text nodes with a space-normalized string value that starts with `'+49'`, as requested.

### See also

- [XPath 1.0 vs XPath 2.0 behavior when multiple nodes passed to a function.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)
- [Why is contains(text(), "string" ) not working in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71253563/290085)