# find a tag with a specific string

Tags: python, html, xpath

As explained in the title I am looking for a tag with a specific character string on this [site](https://www.flashscore.fr/):

My goal is to access a specific result of the search results, which is "PSG" But it does not work and I access the next result.

My goal is to access a specific result from the search results, which is "PSG". But it doesn't work and I get the next result, which is "PSG -19". Here is a screenshot to better understand what I mean:
[image: search results for the word "PSG"]
And here is my current code:
`player_or_team = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable( (By.XPATH,"//div[contains(@class,'searchResults')]/div[contains(@class,'searchResults__section')]/a[contains(@class,'searchResult')]/div[contains(text(), '" + Team + "')]"))) driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", player_or_team)`

I know that the `contains` function searches for a sub string and so all search results meet the condition but my goal is to find a tag that has a text equal to a specific string and so to do that I found several methods like: `[text()="string"]`, `[.="string"]` or `[normalized-space()="string]`
But none of this exception which returns a TimeoutException.

Here are some relevant links that have a similar topic but I don't know why the answer doesn't work for me :
[topic 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39650007/how-to-use-xpath-contains-for-specific-text), [topic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922763/xpath-error-containstext-something-is-not-a-valid-xpath-expression?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [topic 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593753/testing-text-nodes-vs-string-values-in-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

contains() only works on strings

before:

`//div[contains(@class,'searchResults')]`

after:

`//div[@class,'searchResults']`

Comment: I have tried, but in doing so I find no results.