# What does contains() do in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have two almost identical tables, the only difference being the input tag in the first one:

**Table #1**

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>
            <input type="text" name="" value=""/>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Table #2**

```
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

When I use this XPath `//table//tbody//tr[position()=1 and contains(.,input)]` it returns both tables' 1st row, not just the 1st table 1st row as I expect.

However, this XPath `//table//tbody//tr[position()=1]//input` returns just the `input` in the first one.

So, what am I doing wrong? Why the same `input` is associated with both tables? Am I misusing the `.` here somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to an unfortunate choice in function names<sup>1</sup>, many people mistake the purpose of the [**`contains()`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains) function in XPath:

- XPath `contains()` does ***not*** check for ***element***
  containment.
- XPath `contains()` checks for ***substring*** containment.

Therefore, `tr[contains(.,input)]` doesn't do what you think it does.  It actually selects `tr` elements whose [**string-value**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-string-value) contains a substring equal to the string-value of the first immediate child `input` element; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516155/290085) for further details.  (Interestingly, such a predicate simplifies to true because the hierarchical nature of the definition of string-value implies substring containment between string values of parent and child elements.) Anyway, that's clearly not your intent.

To check for descendant *element* containment, use `.//input` instead.  This can be placed as a predicate of `tr` as your first XPath attempted to do, if it's `tr` elements that you wish to select,

```
//table//tbody//tr[position()=1 and .//input]
```

or `table` ([as shown by @Andersson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48669325/290085)), if it's really `table` elements  that you wish to select that contain an `input` descendant element:

```
//table[.//input]
```

---

**Why XPath `contains()` should have been named `string-contains()`**

<sup>1</sup>In the context of XML, which is so strongly based upon the notion of hierarchy, it is natural to assume that *contains* refers to hierarchical containment.  Of the 24 times the word *contains* appears in the original XPath specification, 19 times it means hierarchical node containment; only 5 times does it mean substring containment.  It's no wonder that confusion over `contains()` exists.  The XPath substring `contains()` function should have been named ***string-contains()***.

Comment: @MichaelKay: As to what `tr[contains(.,input)]` does, I believe the predicate will always evaluate to true.  Do you agree?

Comment: If by "always" you mean "when child::input doesn't exist", then yes.

Comment: @MichaelKay: By *always* I mean that whether `child::input` exists 0, 1, or many times, the predicate for `tr[contains(.,input)]` will necessarily be true because the string value of `tr` will necessarily contain the empty string (0 case) , the string value its only `child::input` (1 case), or the string value of its first `child::input` (many case).

Comment: Right - because the input element has a zero-length string value. But in XSLT 2.0 `contains(.,input)` is an error if there is more than one `input` child.

Answer (score 3):

You should try

```
//table[.//input]
```

to fetch `table` node that has `input` descendant