# //parent::* in XPath?

Tags: r, xml, xpath, xml2

Consider this simple example

```
library(xml2)

x <- read_xml("<body>
  <p>Some <b>text</b>.</p>
  <p>Some <b>other</b> <b>text</b>.</p>
  <p>No bold here!</p>
</body>")
```

Now, I want to find all the parents of the nodes containing the string `other`
To do so, I run

```
> xml_find_all(x, "//b[contains(.,'other')]//parent::*")

{xml_nodeset (2)}
[1] <p>Some <b>other</b> <b>text</b>.</p>
[2] <b>other</b>
```

I do not understand why I also get the `<b>other</b>` element as well. In my view there is only one parent, which is the first node.

Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
//b[contains(.,'other')]//parent::*
```

which selects *descendant-or-self* (and you don't want *self*) and *parent*, to

```
//b[contains(.,'other')]/parent::*
```

which selects purely along *parent*, to eliminate `<b>other</b>` from the selection.

Or, better yet, use this XPath:

```
//p[b[contains(.,'other')]]
```

if you want to select all `p` elements with a `b` child whose string-value contains an "other" substring, or

```
//p[b = 'other']
```

if `b`'s string-value is supposed to *equal* `other`.  See also [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48669251/290085)

Comment: ohhh! thanks! so you say that using `//` in `//b[contains(.,'other')]//parent::*` goes two levels down which is why the self is selected (you are the parent of your child)?

Comment: No, there are no elements below `b`.    `//` is *descendant-or-self*;  and you don't want *self* -- you just want `/parent::*` without *self*.  Note that the later two XPath suggestions are simpler.

Comment: Thanks again. I did not know what `p[b = 'other']` woudl directly look for the childs of `p`. I thought the `[` operator was to look for attributes or the current node

Comment: can I ask just a follow up? Assume I am interested in the parents that, say, have some characteristics, such as containing the string 'some'. How would you do that?

Comment: It'd be easier if you asked a new question and gave specific XML and specific targets for selection.  Do watch out for the difference between [***testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085).