# XPath for an element that contains another element with certain text?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I know how to locate `div` inside the `button`:

```
//button/div[contains(text(),'Save')]
```

I'd like to know is it possible to locate any `button` which contains div with text `"Save"` inside?
[image]

```
<button class="PinBetterSave__Button" data-test-id="PinBetterSaveButton"><div class="_w7 _0 _1 _2 _wa _36 _d _b _6">Save</div></button>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try

```
//button[contains(div,'Save')]
```

to locate `button` with **child** `div` that contains specific text.
To locate `button` with **descendant** `div` that contains specific text use

```
//button[contains(.//div,'Save')]
```

Comment: **Warning:** There are [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224863/290085) with both of the provided XPaths.  These problems are subtle, common mistakes and currently missed by OP, who accepted this answer, and by 5 up-voters, who blindly supported what is only superficially correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Issues with the other, currently accepted, answer:** Careful, both XPaths in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54224596/290085) have problems:

1. `//button[contains(div,'Save')]` works in this case, but be aware that it will fail when

   - The `button` contains a `span` or another or no element, rather than a `div`.
   - Other buttons exist with `div` elements whose string values contain the ***substring***, `"Save"`:   `"Save this"`, `"Save that"`, `"Jesus Saves"`, etc.
2. `//button[contains(.//div,'Save')]` also works in this case, but be aware that it will fail if there are multiple `div` descendants and,

   - **XPath 1.0**: the `Save` `div` is not the first `div`.
   - **XPath 2.0+**: it is an error to pass a sequence of more than one item (`div` elements, in this case) as the first argument to `contains()`.

Consider instead this XPath,

```
//button[normalize-space() = 'Save']
```

which will select `button` elements whose space-normalized string value is exactly `"Save"`.

Or, if for substring testing:

```
//button[contains(., 'Save')]
```

### See also

- [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48669251/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)
- [XPath 1.0 vs XPath 2.0 contains() differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)

Comment: Talking about "problems" :) Your warnings do have sense, however, suggested solutions don't really solves OP issue since `//button[normalize-space() = 'Save']` works only if the text content (ignoring starting and trailing spaces) of *button* (not its child *div*) is **equal to** (not **contains**) specific text  and `//button[contains(., 'Save')]` also doesn't answer the question "How to locate any button which contains **div** with text 'Save' inside?"

Comment: @JaSON: **Incorrect.** As I've explained in the referenced "See also" links, *contains* has two meanings, and OPs often confuse the two.  Here, I've been very careful to provide solutions that cover the most likely needs: exact match, the first XPath) and substring containment (the second match).   Anyone having trouble in this area is not looking specifically for a `div` child or descendant element; they're thrown off by how to select their target element based on its string value regardless of any possible additional markup.

Comment: Incorrect just because you think that if OP ask a question OP means not what exactly been asked but something else?:) And all those who search for the same also means something else... Interesting assumption, but IMO it's a road to nowhere:))

Comment: @JaSON: You've always received feedback well on the rare occasions that your answer isn't already perfect.   That I've failed to convince you here must be a shortcoming in my explanation.  If I think of a better way to explain it beyond what I've said here and in the linked answers, I'll try again.