# How to use XPath contains()

Tags: xml, xpath

My XML

```
<r>
  <ul>
    <li>ModelA</li>
    <bi>Foo</bi>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li>ModelB</li>
    <bi>boo</bi>
  </ul>
</r>
```

For specific node value I want to extract the value of the successor node.

Example when li = ModelA get the value of bi which is Foo

My Xpath : `//ul[li[contains(.,'ModelA')]]`

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath does not contain `bi`, so it will not select a `bi`-Node.

Start with

```
//ul/bi
```

which selects the `bi`-node. Now add the conditions in square brackets. The first condition is "the parent node has a `li`-subnode:

```
//ul/bi[../li]
```

The second condition is: that `li`-node contains text:

```
//ul/bi[../li[contains(.,'ModelA')]]
```

However, this might not do what you want in case of multiple `bi` nodes. If you really need the next `bi` node only, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58980899/480982) of [@Jack Fleeting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9448090/jack-fleeting) is probably best.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, this may do the trick:

```
//ul/li[contains(.,'ModelA')]/following-sibling::bi
```

Edit:
Following @Thomas Weller's correct observation in the comments below, here's a simple explanation of this xpath expression:

Your target `<bi>` is a child of the target `<ul>` which itself has another child (`<li>`, hence, the `//ul/li` part), which itself (i.e., the `<li>`) contains the text `li[contains(.,'ModelA')]`). Since both `<li>` and `<bi>`, as children of the same  `<ul>,`are siblings, once that `<li>` is located, the next stop is to locate its sibling  `<bi>` (hence the final `/following-sibling::bi`).

Comment: If you add some explanations, the answer may achieve some learning effect on OP's side. Otherwise it's just a copy/paste fix my issue.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - In the light of a new day (and more coffee) it seems you are right; I shouldn't have rushed the answer. Sorry about that. See edit above.

Answer (score 0):

If it needn't be a successor – if *sibling* suffices – just add the `bi` to the end of your XPath:

```
//ul[li[contains(.,'ModelA')]]/bi
```

will select all `bi` elements with `li` *siblings* that have a string value that contains a `'ModelA` substring.  If you actually want an equality rather than a substring test, you can simplify this to

```
//ul[li='ModelA']/bi
```

See also [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48669251/290085)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to use `contains()` for this? Just use "=".

```
//ul/li[. = 'ModelA')]/following-sibling::bi
```

The `contains()` function is needed only if you want to match a substring, for example if you also want to match a node whose value is `SuperModelA2`