# XPath contains() conditional meaning?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am trying to interpret the meaning of the following condition:

```
<xsl:when test="contains($name,'|') or contains($name,'%7c') or contains($name,'%7C')">
```

Does the above checking whether the variable `name` has `|` in it OR has 7 lower case characters OR 7 uppercase characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it checks whether `$name` contains any of the specified, literal substrings: `|` or `%7c` or `%7C`.

**See [XML XPath Language (XPath), Version 1.0, W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-contains):**

> **Function**: *boolean* **contains**(*string*, *string*)
>
> The contains function returns true if the first argument string contains the second argument string, and otherwise returns false.

**See also:**

- [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48669251/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)

Comment: Thank you so much!  I tested it. It is doing the same thing that you mentioned. Thanks for the quick response.