# Single XPath for several strings?

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I'm trying to get the values from a `span` that doesn't have a class, and I managed to get the value inside one, but I need to get them all at once.
This is my code:

```
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>  
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>

var headings = document.evaluate("//span[contains(., 'one')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, 
null );
var thisHeading = headings.iterateNext();

console.log(thisHeading); // Prints the html element in console
console.log(thisHeading.textContent);
```

How can it put several values in the `document.evaluate()`, so I can print all the values?

Comment: Xpath is one way but if what you want is just get the values and its does not matter to use xpath you can try to get the tag values with getElementsByTagName. All that you need will be; var headings = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (index = 0; index < headings.length; ++index) {
    console.log(headings[index]);
}

Comment: The thing is, i have other span's on the code  and i need to get que values from those one's only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use `or` to test for multiple values `[contains(.,'one') or contains(.,'two') or ...]`

Then you need to use the iterator to loop over the results

```js
var headings = document.evaluate("//span[contains(., 'one') or contains(.,'two')]", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE,
  null);
var thisHeading;

while (thisHeading = headings.iterateNext()) {
  console.log(thisHeading); // Prints the html element in console
  console.log(thisHeading.textContent);
}
```

```html
<span>one</span>
<span>two</span>
<span>three</span>
<span>four</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that XPath `contains()` checks for substrings; for string equality, use `=` against the string value of the node.  See [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48669251/290085)

### XPath 1.0

Test for alternatives via an `or` operator in the predicate:

```
//span[.='one' or .='two' or .='three' or .='four']
```

### XPath 2.0

This can be shortened to:

```
//span[. = ('one','two','three'.'four')]
```