# How do I target a button with extra wrapper tag in XPath?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xpath, puppeteer

I tried targeting the below, but can't seem to get it to work. The error I get is

> Error: Node is either not clickable or not an HTMLElement.

### JavaScript

```
const btn = await page.$x(//button[contains(., 'My Button')])
await btn[0].click()
```

### HTML/XML

```
<div>
<button>
<translate original="My Button">My Button</translate>
</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you truly want substring matching (for example, all of `"My Button"`, `"Not My Button"`, and `"My Buttonless Shirt"`), then use `contains()` as [@Prophet shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70319444/290085).

On the other hand, if you simply want to abstract away *whitespace* (along with any elements wrapping the targeted text), then use [`normalize-space()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-normalize-space):

```
//button[normalize-space() = 'My Button']
```

This selects the `button` element whose space-normalized [string value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) is exactly `'My Button'`.

### See also

- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)
- [What does contains() do in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48669251/290085)

Comment: Thanks for your improving comment and a +1, but shouldn't you use `translate` tag name or `local-name()='translate'` as I used since it's not a button containing `My Button` while `translate` element contains that? +1 back ;)

Comment: Taking the *string value* of `button` renders the name or even existence of any elements wrapping `"My Button"` irrelevant, which I believe is preferred.  If the presence of `translate` is actually important, then to select the `button` element that contains a `translate` element with a string value of `"My Button"`, use this XPath:  `//button[normalize-space(translate) = 'My Button']`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
//button[contains(., 'My Button')]
```

Try

```
//translate[contains(., 'My Button')]
```

Or maybe

```
//*[local-name()='translate' and contains(., 'My Button')]
```

Comment: Good working solution (+1), but better not to [encourage misuse of `contains()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085) where [better alternatives exist](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70320156/290085)