# Why is XPath contains(text(),'substring') not working as expected?

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Let's say I have a piece of HTML like this:

```
<a>Ask Question<other/>more text</a>
```

I can match this piece of XPath:

```
//a[text() = 'Ask Question']
```

Or...

```
//a[text() = 'more text']
```

Or I can use dot to match the whole thing:

```
//a[. = 'Ask Questionmore text']
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41862373/2445415) describes this difference between `.` (dot) and `text()`, but in short the first returns a single element, where the latter returns a list of elements. But this is where it gets a bit weird to me. Because while `text()` can be used to match either of the elements on the list, this is not the case when it comes to the XPath function `contains()`. If I do this:

```
//a[contains(text(), 'Ask Question')]
```

...I get the following error:

> Error: Required cardinality of first argument of contains() is one or zero

How can it be that `text()` works when using a full match (equals), but doesn't work on partial matches (contains)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this markup,

```
<a>Ask Question<other/>more text</a>
```

notice that the `a` element has a text node child (`"Ask Question"`), an empty element child (`other`), and a second text node child (`"more text"`).

Here's how to reason through what's happening when evaluating `//a[contains(text(),'Ask Question')]` against that markup:

1. `contains(x,y)` expects `x` to be a string, but `text()` matches two text nodes.
2. In **XPath 1.0**, the rule for converting multiple nodes to a string is [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#section-String-Functions):

> A node-set is converted to a string by returning the [string-value](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-string-value) of
> the node in the node-set that is ***first*** in [document order](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#dt-document-order). If the
> node-set is empty, an empty string is returned.  [Emphasis added]

3. In **XPath 2.0+**, it is an error to provide a sequence of text nodes to a function expecting a string, so `contains(text(),'substr')` will cause an error for more than one matching text node.

In your case...

- XPath 1.0 would treat `contains(text(),'Ask Question')` as

  ```
  contains('Ask Question','Ask Question')
  ```

  which is `true`.  On the other hand, be sure to notice that `contains(text(),'more text')` will evaluate to `false` in XPath 1.0.  Without knowing the (1)-(3) above, this can be counter-intuitive.
- XPath 2.0 would treat it as an error.

### Better alternatives

- If the goal is to find all `a` elements whose string value contains the substring, 
  `"Ask Question"`:

  ```
  //a[contains(.,'Ask Question')]
  ```

  This is the most common requirement.
- If the goal is to find all `a` elements with an immediate text node child equal to `"Ask Question"`:

  ```
  //a[text()='Ask Question']
  ```

  This can be useful when wishing to exclude strings from descendent elements in `a` such as if you want this `a`,

  ```
  <a>Ask Question<other/>more text</a>
  ```

  but not this `a`:

  ```
  <a>more text before <not>Ask Question</not> more text after</a>
  ```

### See also

- [How `contains()` handles a nodeset first arg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516155/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() for specific text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39650007/290085)
- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)

Comment: Gem of an answer. Clears all the doubts (+1).

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that the `contains` function doesn't accept a nodeset as input - it only accepts a string. (Well, it may be engine dependent, because it works for `Python`'s `lxml` module. According to the specification, it should convert the value of the first node in the set to a string and act on that. See also [XPath contains(text(),'some string') doesn't work when used with node with more than one Text subnode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more?rq=1))

`//a[text() = 'Ask Question']` is matching any `a` elements which contain a text node which equals `Ask Question`.

`//a[text() = 'more text']` is matching any `a` elements which contain a text node which equals `more text`.

So both of these expressions match the same `a` element.

You can re-work your query to `//a[text()[contains(., 'Ask Question')]]` so that the `contains` method will only act on a single text node at a time.

Comment: You wrote "So both of these expressions match the same a element." but strings `'Ask Question'` and `'more text'` are not identical, so how matching `a` element with text EQUALS to 'Ask Question' and matching `a` element with text EQUALS to 'more text' are matching the SAME element? This breaks some basic logic!!! I see this works, but it is still unclear to me.

Comment: Excellent explanation by Keith Hall. Helped me with span[text()= ...] having an icon with it.