# Get a data from this XML doc using Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath, count

I want to know the number of persons with `"Lot"` in their addres, from this XML doc using Xpath.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<personnes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="personne.xsd">
    <personne id="n1" pays="MA">
        <nom>Ayoubi</nom>
        <prenom>Nezard</prenom>
        <dat_naiss>1999-02-05</dat_naiss>
        <telephone>+21266666666</telephone>
        <adress>
            Lotxxx Num: 38
            <ville>Rabat</ville>
        </adress>
    </personne>
    <personne id="n11" pays="Fr">
        <nom>Karimi</nom>
        <prenom>Hamdani</prenom>
        <dat_naiss>2000-05-07</dat_naiss>
        <telephone>+21266666666</telephone>
        <adress>
            rue xxx Num: 18
            <ville>Grenoble</ville>
        </adress>
    </personne>
</personnes>
```

I Tested my Xpaths here : [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html)

I tried so many Xpaths but i don't know how to apply the count function on this Xpath : `//adress/contains(text()[1],"Lot")` that returns to me :

```
Boolean='true'

Boolean='false'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This XPath,

```
count(//personne[adress[contains(.,'Lot')]])
```

will count the number of `personne` elements with an `adress` child whose string-value contains a `"Lot"` substring.  This will include `"Lot"` substrings wrapped within other markup.

This XPath,

```
count(//personne[adress/text()[contains(.,'Lot')]])
```

will do the same but exclude `"Lot"` substrings wrapped within other markup.

Both XPath expressions work with XPath 1.0 and up.

### See also

- [Testing text() nodes vs string values in XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34593753/290085)
- [Why is XPath contains(text(),'substring') not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69909751/290085)

Answer (score 1):

In XPath-1.0, the expression would have to be

```
contains(//adress/text()[1],"Lot")
```

This would give you the result of `true`. To get the result of `true` and `false`, you would have to iterate over the `//adress/text()[1],"Lot"` nodes, preferably with an `xsl:for-each`.

---

Following up, you can get the count of the `personne` elements that contain the string `Lot` in its `adress` child by using the following expression:

```
count(contains(//personne/adress/text()[1],"Lot"))
```

Its result should be `1`.