# How to find the xpath for an element by text containing three dots

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find the xpath for an element that contains three dots instead of text. Once I expand the element by clicking on arrow in DOM model html it returns the text.
The following xpath returns nothing unfortunately:

```
//button[contains(text(),'Pending')]
```

What's the right solution?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The text content of that element is not a three dots but `Pending  ()`. You see the `...` only because there is no room to present the text there until you expand the element. So, generally this `//button[contains(text(),'Pending')]` should work.
You can also try this XPath expression:

```
//button[contains(.,'Pending')]
```

It means "a button element with **any** attribute containing `Pending` value"
It is more general and should work.
To understand why `//button[contains(text(),'Pending')]` did not work see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655549/xpath-containstext-some-string-doesnt-work-when-used-with-node-with-more) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909751/why-is-xpath-containstext-substring-not-working-as-expected?noredirect=1&lq=1). There are more explanations about this.

Comment: That's interesting because the generic search works //button[contains(.,'Pending')] but by text() search does NOT  //button[contains(text(),'Pending')]. Anyway thank you!

Comment: It's not a generic search. I will explain more

Comment: Got it, thx! But still I wonder why //button[contains(text(),'Pending')] doesn't return any elements ?

Comment: See the updated post with links. You can google more :)