XPath not handling self-closing tags
I am trying to make an XPath path to describe a node in html. This node contains a self-closing tag and that is making my XPath not work. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug in the xml2 package?
library(xml2)
TestHTML = '<html> <body> <h2>ABC <br/>DEF</h2> </body> </html>'
Parsed = read_html(TestHTML)

# The text looks OK
H2 = xml_find_first(Parsed, "//h2")
xml_text(H2)
## [1] "ABC DEF"

# But when built into the path, it fails
xml_find_first(Parsed, "//h2[contains(text(), 'DEF')]")
## {xml_missing}
## <NA>

If I remove the <br/> part, it works fine.
I am using xml2_1.3.6.

Contains expect as it first parameter 1 string. If you add a br inside the h2 the h2 now has 2 text nodes and therefore contains  fails. If you change text() to a ., it will work because that notation tells the engine, to first combine all text nodes into 1 string and therefore contains works again

@SiebeJongebloed Thank you for your comment.  As you see in the output, xml_text(H2)   produces a single string, not two.  Do you have any suggestion for expressing the path differently that will make this work?

Try //h2[text()[contains(., ' DEF']] (Just a suggestion, because I don't know what version of XPath you are using - you should always say.)

I do not know what xml_text  under the hood does, but  your H2 does have 2 text-nodes and therefore fails.  try @MichaelKay oprion or try  //h2[contains(., ' DEF']

I added the version of xml2 that I am using to my question.

Both suggestions with contains(., 'DEF') work. I like @MichaelKay 's suggestion better because it is more explicitly restricted to the text.   Thank you both for your help.  @MichaelKay if you write up your solution as an answer, I will accept it as the desired solution.

See this Answer for a excellent explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69915361/3710053

@SiebeJongebloed Thanks, that reference was very helpful.
