# What does contains(.,'substring') mean in XPath and what's its equivalent in CSS?

Tags: html, css, xml, xpath

Able to locate all div elements in UI page using this XPATH locator : `//div[contains(.,'')]` irrespective of the text inside them. What does `.,''` mean ?

Consider below example:

XPath to specifically select `div` with text - `'Apple'` would be `//div[contains(.,'Apple')]`.

What is its CSS equivalent ?

```
<div>
<span> Apple </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`//div[contains(.,'Apple')]`

1. `//div` means to select all `div` elements in the document.
2. `//div[` *predicate* `]` means to filter those per the given *predicate*.
3. `contains(` *str*`,` *substr* `)` means to return true iff *str* contains the substring, *substr*.
4. `.` is the *context node*.  (See [Current node vs. Context node in XSLT/XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1022345/290085)) Within the predicate of your XPath, it will be a `div` element.  When passed as a function parameter with type string, it will be converted to the *string value* of the node.
5. The *string-value* of an element is equal to the concatenation of the string values of its children elements.

Therefore, your XPath returns all `div` elements in the document whose string value contains the `'Apple'` substring.

There is no CSS equivalent.

### See also

- [Is there a CSS selector for elements containing certain text?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1520429/290085)
- [How to use XPath contains() here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1064968/290085)