# How can I click a button using Selenium and Python without a Button Class?

Tags: python, selenium, button, automation

[image: This is a picture of the HTML in question. I am trying to click the time slot @ 4:34PM. This one in particular is "Jump 65" and the previous timeslot is Jump 64. I'd like the ability to specify and click any of the buttons with a timeslot.]

This is a picture of the HTML in question. I am trying to click the time slot @ 4:34PM. This one in particular is "Jump 65" and the previous timeslot is Jump 64. I'd like the ability to specify and click any of the buttons with a timeslot.

Comment: Why not try using the `text()` function? `//a[text()='your text here']`

Comment: should work `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//a[text()="4:34 PM"]').click()`

Comment: Adding to sound waves, You can also use 
"contains" and "logical operators" if needed.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064968/how-to-use-xpath-contains-here