# XSLT: How to filter a node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm trying to remove the node which contains (`Descriptor=ID1`) but it returns below error.

XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
    <Entry>
        <Line>1</Line>
        <Reference Descriptor="ID1">
            <ID type="ID">gbgfdbnfg</ID>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Descriptor="ID2">
            <ID type="ID">tshbtdsg</ID>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Descriptor="ID3">
            <ID type="ID">rhbdgb</ID>
        </Reference>
    </Entry>
</Data>
```

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    
    <xsl:template match="*[contains(Reference/@Descriptor,'ID1')]">
        <!-- Do nothing -->
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Error:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of `fn:contains() ("ID1", "ID2")`

Expected Output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<Data>
    <Entry>
        <Line>1</Line>
        <Reference Descriptor="ID2">
            <ID type="ID">tshbtdsg</ID>
        </Reference>
        <Reference Descriptor="ID3">
            <ID type="ID">rhbdgb</ID>
        </Reference>
    </Entry>
</Data>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<xsl:template match="*[contains(Reference/@Descriptor,'ID1')]">
```

to

```
<xsl:template match="Reference[@Descriptor='ID1']">
```

because

- It's `Reference` elements with the targeted `Descriptor` attribute values that you wish to omit, not parents of `Reference` elements.
- You want an equality check, not a substring containment check, of the value of the `Descriptor` attribute.

### See also

- [`contains()` means *contains a substring*, **not** *contains a node*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46516155/290085)
- [XPath 1.0 vs 2.0+ different contains() behavior explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71255563/290085)

---

**Update per follow-up asking about a true substring test need...**

> What if it contains `<Reference Descriptor="Name: ID1">` and `<Reference Descriptor="Item: ID2">` and `<Reference Descriptor="Book: ID3">` and I would like to remove node which contains `'Name'`

Then use this XPath to avoid the error caused by giving `contains()` a node set or sequence as its first argument:

```
<xsl:template match="Reference[@Descriptor[contains(.,'Name')]]">
```

Note that `starts-with()` could be used instead of `contains()`.

Comment: Thank you. What if it contains <Reference Descriptor="Name: ID1"> and <Reference Descriptor="Item: ID2"> and <Reference Descriptor="Book: ID3"> and I would like to remove node which contains 'Name'

Comment: Answer updated to show how to test for a substring of the `Descriptor` attribute value while avoiding the original error.